# Custom Language switcher in cake php

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

How can i create my own  language switcher  in cake php. I do not want to use google api. Guys please suggest me with good solutions.

Comment: This is cakephp question. wrongly specified magento tag

Comment: Check my article: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kicaj/2013/01/27/internationalization_with_static_and_dynamic_content_routing_and_switching

Answer (score 1):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

This is how you can create.
__() --> translate function

```
translation files
/app/Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (English)
/app/Locale/fre/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (French)
/app/Locale/por/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (Portuguese)
```

In appController

```
  // App Controller Code.
        public function beforeFilter() {
            $locale = Configure::read('Config.language');
            if ($locale && file_exists(VIEWS . $locale . DS . $this->viewPath)) {
             //  e.g. use /app/View/fre/Pages/tos.ctp instead of /app/View/Pages/tos.ctp
                $this->viewPath = $locale . DS . $this->viewPath;
            }
        }
```

In place of `$locale = Configure::read('Config.language');` add code passed from your language switcher
e.g. Dropdown of language switcher.User selects english. Pass and check it in appController. Rest would be handled by the code